# Error message while parsing json in Python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

Am using below code for parsing json coming from url. But I am getting this  error:

```
ex= data['e']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Here is my code:

```
html = urlopen("http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/myresource")
content = html.read()
data = json.loads(content.decode("utf8"))
ex = data['e']
print(ex)
```

And here is the JSON:

```
[  
  {  
    "c":"-1.00",
    "c_fix":"-1.00",
    "ccol":"chr",
    "cp":"-0.37",
    "cp_fix":"-0.37",
    "e":"NSE",
    "id":"13564339",
    "l":"269.50",
    "l_cur":"&#8377;269.50",
    "l_fix":"269.50",
    "lt":"Feb 17, 3:56PM GMT+5:30",
    "lt_dts":"2017-02-17T15:56:16Z",
    "ltt":"3:56PM GMT+5:30",
    "pcls_fix":"270.5",
    "s":"0",
    "t":"SBIN"
  }
]
```

Comment: the result of the parsing is a list, you are then accessing it using `data['e']`, hence the error, try `data[0]['e']`

Comment: `data[0]['e']`; or use a `for item in data: item['e']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `data[0]['e']` because the top layer of original JSON is a list.